# Include includes in subproject

Tags: c++, cmake

I have projectB as a subproject of projectA. Both projects contain an include directory for storing header libraries. The folder structure looks like this:

```
projectA/CMakeLists.txt
projectA/A.cpp
projectA/include/projectB/CMakeLists.txt
projectA/include/projectB/B.h
projectA/include/projectB/include/boost
projectA/include/projectB/include/...
```

Inside **B.h**, I am using Boost, so the include line looks like this:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
```

In **A.cpp**, I am including B.h.

```
#include <B.h>
```

In **projectA/CMakeLists.txt**, I am including projectB and all of its includes like this:

```
include_directories(
    include/projectB
    include/projectB/include/boost 
    include/projectB/include/...)
```

If I didn't include all library directories that projectB uses, I cannot compile, as the compiler cannot find boost. (I get an error which says: `boost/algorithm/string.hpp: No such file or directory`)

Is there a simpler process to have projectA import all includes from projectB and change the paths to reflect this project hierarchy?

Comment: Can't you just include `include/projectB/include`? Then when it looks for boost it should find it?

Comment: @Tas That is an option that I can do. Is it typical to include just the single include directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With modern CMake (i.e. 3.x) it is not recommended any more to use `include_directories`. The alternative is to define the include directories per target with appropriate "visibility".

Assuming, `projectA` is a static or shared library defined in `projectA/CMakeLists.txt` as follows, with `projectA_SOURCES` being a list of all source files (i.e. not header files) for that library.

```
add_library(projectA ${projectA_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(projectA
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/projectB/include
           ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/projectB/include/boost
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/projectB)
```

Then, in `projectB/CMakeLists.txt` after having target `projectB` being defined (either as a library or executable, that does not matter):

```
target_include_directories(projectB
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/projectA/include
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/projectA)
target_link_library(projectB
    PUBLIC projectA)
```